# Magento 2 Save custom entity primary key

Tags: magento2, api, best-practice, interface

Before all I am using Magento 2.1.2, with a custom entity.

I am trying to save multiple row in a flat table that I have created with 
`$connection->insertMultiple($this->getMainTable(), $answers);`

For that I am using the following code to populate missing row lines

```
$dataUserAnswer = $this->dataUserAnswerFactory->create();

$this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
    $dataUserAnswer,
    $answers,
    'XXX\YYY\Api\Data\UserAnswerInterface'
);
$userAnswers[] = $this->dataObjectProcessor->buildOutputDataArray(
    $dataUserAnswer,
    'XXX\YYY\Api\Data\UserAnswerInterface'
);
```

With the classes `Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper` and `Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor`

Here is the result I get

```
[0] => array(7) {
    ["id"] => NULL
    ["poll_question_id"] => int(1)
    ["poll_answer_id"] => string(1) "1"
    ["value"] => string(0) ""
    ["customer_id"] => string(1) "1"
    ["created_at"] => NULL
    ["updated_at"] => NULL
}
```

Which is nearly what I want except for the `id` entry.
In my Api/Data/Interface I declare a constant `const ID = 'id';` with getter and setter `getId()` / `setId($id)`.
I took a look at `Customer` module to have an exemple to build my entity.
Magento best practice is to have the primary key as `entity_id`.

I understand that `buildOutputDataArray` use `Reflexion` class to retrive getter and then deduce entity fields to fill missing fields.

My questions are :
 - What is the best pratice for API interface constante / setter / getter ? `id` ? `entity_id` ?
 - If I am taking a look at `Customer`entity, primary key is `entity_id` but constante is `id`. Do I miss something ? Am I doing this the wrong way ?

Hope my problem is clear.
Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer my own question for people seeing this post.

I had to create `setEntityId` / `getEntityId` in my API interface and remove the `getId` / `setId` because it already exist in the parent class `\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::getId` so it does not matter if it is not present in the API interface.
And add the following code in my model as for Magento 1:

```
/**
 * Name of object id field
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_idFieldName = 'entity_id';
```

I had take a look at the wrong entity for my exemple...